# SWIFT, iOS, Sharing Extension, url and html

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create sharing extention that takes url and html and sends it to server. The code worked 2 times, and than stopped. I'm really lost. Please help:

```
    override func didSelectPost() {
        let url = self.extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem
        let itemProvider = url.attachments![0] as NSItemProvider
        
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil) { (url, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    // Handle error
                    return
                }
                
                guard let shareURL = url as? URL else {
                    return
                }
                
                // Get the HTML
                guard let htmlString = try? String(contentsOf: shareURL) else {
                    return
                }
                
                let shareData = ShareData(url: shareURL.absoluteString, html: htmlString)
                guard let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(shareData) else {
                    return
                }
                
                // Do  sending it to a server
                let token = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.readout.app")?.string(forKey: "FirebaseAccessToken")
                            let url = URL(string: "http://blabla.com/api/article")!
                            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                            request.httpMethod = "POST"
                            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                            request.setValue("Bearer \(token ?? "")", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                            request.httpBody = jsonData
                            
                            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                                if let error = error {
                                    // Handle error
                                    return
                                }
                                
                                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                                    return
                                }
                                
                                if response.statusCode == 200 {
                                    // Successfully sent data
                                } else {
                                    // Handle non-200 response
                                }
                            }
                            task.resume()
                        }
                    }

                self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

I checked that I receive the token from the main app. Also it is wierd, that the extention worked with exactly the same code 2 times, randomly. But now, I can't reproduce the succesful case. I'm very new to swift and do have very little understanding of the issue :-) appreciate sany help. Thanks

Comment: You are dealing with assincronous code. So, it's more common then you think the code work a few times then didn't. That being said... put a debug on line let token  = ... and see is the variable token is what you expect after this line. (I would start from there)

Comment: the code inside the  URLSession ran inside a background loop, if you try do to anything UI related there the word ENDS. Also you have a memory cycle in your code. The URLSession is holded by "let task" and the struct or class you are overriding the didSelectPost is holder by whatever you must be putting inside de if statement. Show de real code and we could help more. (I meant a breakpoint on the comment before)

Answer (score 0):

You are having inconsistent results because you are calling self.extensionContext!.completeRequest() as soon as you have made your http request.

When you call completeRequest() you are telling the OS that your extension has finished and the OS will consequently terminate your extension.
It succeeded initially probably by chance and you had a very fast connectivity at that time and the http request had the chance to get made before the OS killed your extension.

To ensure the html gets sent out you would need to move your call to completRequest() to within the http tasks response. Probably a good idea to put a timeout value there in case your server doesn't respond within a certain time (though the OS will probably kill your extension anyway if it doesn't hear from it after a certain time).

But have you considered what you will do if there's no connectivity or your server is down? You can't wait and retry later in an extension, so what are you going do?

You need to think about things like this to architect your extension and app thoroughly.